# Есть ли среда разработки для ipad для программирования на си?

Tags: ide

Здравствуйте!

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли срада разработки для ipad, что бы писать на языке си. Нужно много всякой фигни писать, не более 200 строк. Всего на два месяца, ноутбук покупать дорого и неудобно.
Пробовал писать ideone, очень неудобно из за работы через браузер и отсутвия нормального интернета.

Прошу без троллинга, только по существу.

Спасибо.

Comment: Так прям ваще нет :)?

Comment: видимо они есть только для html/javascript. Но если что, я бы брал Rasberry Pi, ставил туда любой удобный Linux дистрибутив и дальше с помощью ssh/vnc получал нормальный доступ. А также прикупил дополнительную клавиатуру.